# How to split the fixed number of rows in a data into Xtest, Xtrain , Ytrain and Ytest without train_test_split function in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, train-test-split

I have the data set with 80 columns. In python I want to split the data into first 60 as train data and the 13 as test data. The data gets split randomly if I use train_test_split function. I don't want random data for train.

E.g: Data set columns looks like the below:

**Date | dependent_variable | independent_variable_1 | independent_variable_2**

```
train = data[:80] 
test = data[13:]
```

From this how to split the dependent variable and independent variable.(Xtrain,Xtest, Ytrain and Ytest)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Training on 60 column and testing on 33 column doesn't make any sense. Training is done on a fraction of rows having same column as that of testing data

Comment: Training sets and the test sets should have the same attributes, then only when you do a prediction for the test data set it will provide you appropriate results.

Comment: @anon_143 not an issue. We can make it as 80 and 13.

Comment: What I was saying that attributes should be same, similar to what @SUN has said. Training and testing should be done on same columns, It's the rows that we split. See Sentdex videos of ML on youtube if you are just starting out with ML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The data gets split randomly if I use train_test_split function. I don't want random data for train.

By default its random, yes, but you can make it NOT random.

If you call the function doing `train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=False)`. Notice the parameter **shuffle**:

> Whether or not to shuffle the data before splitting

You will achieve your objective of splitting without random splits.

Finally, train_test_split splits your dataset rows using the test_size, so if you want to do it manually, keep in mind that you should split the rows and not the columns, and keep the respective columns for the X and the y.

Comment: Thank you so much. And one doubt, how to store only the required variable(columns) from a data set in a data frame.

Comment: if X is an array of arrays, pd.DataFrame([X[0]]) would create a dataframe of the array number 0 in X